# What's wrong with the following reasoning of getting 2 (or more) consecutive heads in n tosses?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We need the number of ways to obtain 2 or more consecutive heads in n trials.

**My reasoning:** Let's consider how many times 2 consecutive heads won't be encountered and subtract from $2^n$.

Let's consider alternate positions that are already placed with tails and heads. So, we have **THTHTH**.....

Don't disturb the existing T's. We just have to fill in H's with 1 or more T's. As there are n/2 H's, This can be done in $(n/2) C 1$ + $(n/2) C 2$ + .... $(n/2) C (n/2)$ ways. Let this summation be **S**.

The other combo is **HTHTHT**..... So the summation is now 2S.

So, our required answer is $2^n$ - 2S for the ways to get atleast 1 pair of consecutive heads.

I know the answer has to do with Fibonacci numbers, but I wanted to know how this reasoning is wrong. What I'm I assuming wrongly ?

Comment: When did you count HTTHTTH...?

Comment: "Let's consider alternate positions that are already placed with tails and heads. ..." :: "Don't disturb the existing T's....".  What is the justification for starting your consideration with the requirement that you have Heads and Tails in alternating positions?  If I am interpreting your analysis correctly, you are saying that where ever the H's are *initially*, you can't place another H right next to any of them.  If I am not mistaken, this does not justify the presumption that you must start with alternating Heads and Tails.  Am I overlooking something in your analysis?

Comment: User2661923, I'm saying that the alternately placed H's can be replaced by 1 or more T's. So, we'll get more combinations of non-consecutive H's till we reach all T's (TTTTT.....)

Comment: David, HTTHTTH will be considered when we start replacing some of the alternately placed H's with T's. Eventually, we'll reach TTTTT....

Comment: @Abhishek, use latex code to write mathematical symbols.

Comment: @Mathlearner, it's done.

Comment: If I'm understanding your argument correctly, then with $n = 4$, your initial positions are **HTHT** and **THTH**. With **HTHT**, you can get $4$ possibilities: **HTHT**, **TTHT**, **HTTT**, and **TTTT**. With **THTH**, you can get $4$ possibilities too: **THTH**, **TTTH**, **THTT**, and **TTTT**. The problems are (1) **TTTT** is counted twice, and (2) you are missing **HTTH**.

Comment: @VTand, thanks. That explains many things. So we have to go by the (sort of) brute force way and Fibonacci numbers. On a lighter note, in this particular example, since we count an occurrence twice and miss one occurrence, shouldn't we arrive at the right answer eventually ?

Comment: @Abhishek Yes, you would get the right answer by coincidence for $n = 4$.

Comment: So It seems you understand now how you fail to count HTTHTTH.... Fortunately, Fibonacci numbers are not much more "brute force" than powers of $2.$ There is even a closed form for the $n$th Fibonacci number.